# Not able to connect to remote server from WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, networking, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making an application which basically just needs to send a piece of XML to a server and return. I'm having trouble however getting this to work and getting very strange errors

```
public bool Post(string data)
    {
        string server="http://my-lan-computer:9091/foo"
        bool success = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            client.PostAsync(server, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).Wait(); //error here
            success = true;
        } catch { }

        return success;

    }
```

The server I'm posting to is not localhost, but it is a computer on my local network. I get this error deeply nested:

```
innerException: {"An error occurred while sending the request."}

innerException: {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

innerException: {"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 123.123.123.123:9091"}
```

I have the internet client capability on my application. I can access my local network and internet by other store applications. I can access the resource in firefox get proper behavior. I don't have a firewall enabled nor an anti-virus that would block these ports

What could possibly cause this obscure error? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like the response might be coming from the server. What is the server? Is it IIS? WCF service of some sort? Can you check web.config? Check in Fiddler to compare a request from a WinRT app and another client that succeeds in connecting to the same service? Maybe it has specific requirements on the http verb or headers of the request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To access the LAN, you must declare the `Private Network` capability in your application manifest. Note that this is different than the `Internet` capability.

Comment: Heh, didn't notice that option. Strange thing is that this WAS working about a week ago. I'm thinking enforcement might have been "broken" in development, but some windows update or visual studio update fixed it

Comment: For those who aren't able to find their applicatino manifest file: it's the .appxmanifest file in your Solution Explorer