# Windows Store Application Http Requests Only Work After Manifest Change

Tags: c#, windows, http, windows-store-apps

I am currently building a windows store application and I am running into what I now think is a bug.

All my http requests fail except when I make a change to the application manifest then they will work on the first run but straight after that the next web request will fail.

The strange thing is that in order for me to get it to work again I will have to remove a capability from the manifest, even if it is an important one such as the internet capability then the application will work!

Here are the headers I am passing in my HttpClient request:

```
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "keep-alive");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "xx.xx.x.xxx");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36");
requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
```

Even when I get a web request to hit the server it will always fail on the next call.

Here is the exception I get when it fails:

```
InnerException = {"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.98.0.181:80"}
```

We have deployed the Web API services on IIS and the application is running on a tablet that connects to the server using a VPN.

The tablet is running Symantic Endpoint Protection which is managed externally.

Is there a caching option I can turn of on the device that could be causing this or a setting I have overlooked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to connect to remote server from WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592766/not-able-to-connect-to-remote-server-from-winrt)

Comment: @chuex please note that I have tried different variations with the capabilites including the **Private Networks** with no luck. I currently have the **Private Networks** and **Internet (Client)** capabilities ticked.